# cURL function in while loop not working PHP

Tags: php, curl

I am wanting cURL to retry when cURL fails, but I have a situation like this
My function inside while loop is not working.
But when I remove the while loop, it works normally again.

Here is my function snippet:

```
function Curl($url){
    $total_curl = 1;
    $isRunning = true;
    $sleep = 1;
    while ($isRunning){
        $curl = curl_init($url);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_REFERER, $this->url ?? $url);

        //for debug only!
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT,10);

        $resp = curl_exec($curl);

        if((!$resp || curl_errno($curl))){
            if($total_curl > 3){
                $isRunning = false;
            }

            sleep($sleep);
        }

        curl_close($curl);
        $total_curl++;
    }
    
    return $resp;
}
```

Comment: you need to stop the loop on success

Comment: also as your retrying the same url you don't need to create a new curl instance and options, within the loop you only need curl_exec, and checks

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your while loop. If the curl is successful your while loop will run forever because the `$total_curl` variable is never checked in the nested if.

I would suggest using recursion for this, sicne i find it a bit cleaner and this is how i would approach it:

```
/**
 * Solve using recursion cause it's fun
 */
function Curl($url, $times_run = 0)
{
    // Condition that will break recursion, in this case if curl failed and run 3 times
    if ($times_run > 3) {
        return;
    }
    $curl = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_REFERER, $url); // replace this with $this->url ?? $url if you want but i removed it since i am not inside a class

    //for debug only!
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);

    $resp = curl_exec($curl);

    // Start recursive function if curl is not successful
    if ((!$resp || curl_errno($curl))) {
        Curl($url, $times_run++);
    }

    curl_close($curl);
    
    return $resp;
}
```

The alternative would be to keep your way and just add a `return $resp` at the end of your while loop like so:

```
function Curl($url)
{
    $total_curl = 1;
    $isRunning = true;
    while ($isRunning) {
        $curl = curl_init($url);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_REFERER, $this->url ?? $url);

        //for debug only!
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);

        $resp = curl_exec($curl);

        if ((!$resp || curl_errno($curl))) {
            if ($total_curl > 3) {
                $isRunning = false;
            }
            curl_close($curl);
            $total_curl++;
        } else {
            curl_close($curl);
            return $resp;
        }
    }
}
```

I hope this helps with your problem, cheers.